# How to change bootstrap progress-bar dynamically from .cs file in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter-bootstrap progress bar in asp.net. When the form will load the `width` is `90%`. There is a button in form and when it will fire then I want to change width to 100%. How can I do it?

When Form loads

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-striped active">
    <div class="progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 90%"></>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery : http://jquery.com/

```
<div class="progress progress-bar-striped active">
    <div id="progressbar" class="progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style="width: 90%"></>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#yourbuttonid").click(function(){
    $("#progressbar").css("width", "90%");
  });
});
</script>
```